# Find exact match of string and the matching position

Tags: c#, regex

I want to search keyword stored in variable `kw` in large length text and find the **FIRST**  **position** at which keyword is found .
Below code doesn't do **EXACT** keyword match .

```
if (webData.IndexOf(kw, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1)
{
     found = true;
     int pos = webData.IndexOf(kw, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); 
}
```

how to do it using regex ?

```
Match match = Regex.Match(webData, @"^kw$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (match.Success)
{
  int pos = //Matching position
}
```

Comment: yes , a keyword of string type

Comment: Define what "keyword" means in your case. Is it any text that's surrounded by spaces or punctuation? Can the word itself contain numbers, dashes, punctuation, etc.? You have `IgnoreCase` turned on, which automatically says it's not "exact". Give a few examples of full-text inputs and the keywords that can match.

Comment: With the information you provided, I don't understand why you want to switch to using `Regex` really

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
Match match = Regex.Match(webData, @"\b"+Regex.Escape(kw)+@"\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (match.Success)
{
  int pos = match.Index;
}
```

For exact match you need to use boundary represented by `\b`

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.aspx)

Comment: What if `kw` contains regular expression syntax? Wouldn't you have to escape this?

Answer (score 1):

The [`Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.aspx) will have an `Index` property doing just what you want:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(webData, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (match.Success)
{
  int pos = match.Index;
}
```

> Index - The position in the original string where the first character of the captured substring is found. (Inherited from Capture.)

Comment: `^kw$` is the same as saying `webData.Equals("kw")`. Also, doesn't `match.Index` give the same value as `webData.IndexOf()`?